# how to to apply Editext in my searchview

Tags: android, android-edittext, searchview

hey guys i want to apply Editext into searchview. how can i do that? how to modified it in able to work in my searchview?

here is my code

```
EditText myFilter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myFilter);
    myFilter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                      int count, int after) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                  int before, int count) {
            dataAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
        }
    });

    dataAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
        public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
            return dbHelper.fetchCountriesByName(constraint.toString());
        }
    });
```